# LockerService in spring '17

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

There is one critical update in Sprint '17 release, which is *Enable Lightning LockerService Security*. How will this affect lightning components? We currently don't use lightning components except Process builder in our project. So is it going to affect Process builder functionality as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locker service only applies to custom components currently - standard components/applications run in system mode and are not impacted by the LS rollout.

Comment: Thanks Doug. So that means activation locker service does not impact on process builder but it will impact on other custom lightning components. Right?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find all the documentation about the impact on your lightning components:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html

E.g.: Standard markup like `<input>` will crash if you do not replace it with `<lightning:input>`

I have not read anything about `Process Builder` impact (yet).

Comment: Simon would you please elaborate on "standard markup like <input> will crash..."? There are no open issues to this effect and there is definitely no requirement to switch to lightning:input.

Comment: When the Lockerservice has been activated, I have got error messages and not working component until I fix the "translation" `input` => `lightning:input`.

If I am wrong, weird that everything was broken :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to your post on this or a support case ID where you let Salesforce know about this issue with <input>? I'm looking to get the issue fixed but need your help to understand the specifics of the issue you encountered.